# xpath finds element in developers console but not in scrapy.response

Tags: html, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the price from the first ticket [here](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/buzz-beach-ball-tickets/buzz-beach-ball-sporting-park-7-25-1771684.html) page using this xpath:

`'.//*[@class="price"]/text()'`

This works in the developer's console, but not when I run it in the scrapy shell using response.xpath. I have also tried to following in the shell:

`'.//*[@class="initial"]/div[@class="price"]/text()'`

and

`'//*[@id="tVB901769989"]/div[1]/div[4]'` (although I don't think that the id property can be used in the shell like this).

Is there something wrong with the xpaths that I've used, or is there some thing different with the way the page works? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this happens because you are checking at different requests, the page you see doesn't have the information you need inside that file, but it gets it dynamically, in this case from: www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=1771684

There you can check the prices on json format, I think this is for one item:

```
{
   "s":"Section 111",
   "r":"8-22",
   "q":"4",
   "p":"692.00",
   "i":"VB782041491",
   "d":"111",
   "n":"Zone Seating. The seller is committing to procure these tickets for you upon receipt of your order. After you place your order and your order is confirmed, we guarantee that your tickets will be within the listed zone
 or section listed or one comparable and that you will receive these tickets in time for the event or
 your money back. Orders exceeding four tickets may be split up into different rows within the requested
 zone or section.",
   "f":"0",
   "l":"Section 111",
   "g":"0",
   "e":"0",
   "h":"07/21/15",
   "t":"0",
   "v":"",
   "c":"84352",
   "z":"1",
   "rhdn":"0",
   "ind":"0",
   "sd":"0"
}
```

where `p` contains the price.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just have two questions now. The first is how you got the link for the json data of the ticket. It seems like the file would have to be retrieved from a request or something. Also, since it turns out that the price has to be retrieved from the JSON data, is there any way that this could be done inside of a loop?Btw, I'm using scrapy to get the data from the previous page (with the events and links to all of the corresponding ticket pages) and the lowest price from each ticket page.

Comment: you need to check all the requests visiting a page does, I personally use firebug (on firefox). About the "loop", I don't really get what you mean, but json can be parsed into a dictionary and then you can get the info (you could get it with regex the nasty way), but there are lots of ways.

Comment: I was able to find the json files that each ticket uses, but now I need to locate the first price (denoted with "p") on the page and then store that into a Scrapy item loader. Do you know the best way to do this? Would it be best to use some jquery function or should I use regex in this case?

Comment: with the `json` module?